# Determining Whether a Function is Surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I've been trying this problem for quite some time now and I just can't seem to figure it out, even after looking at numerous sources for help.

Consider the function  $f:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f((m,n)) = (m - 2n, n-m)$

a) Determine whether $f$ is one-to-one.

b) Determine whether $f$ is onto.

I was able to conclude that $f$ is one-to-one but I just can't seem to get if its onto. I understand what being surjective means; In loose terms, a function is surjective if the entire codomain is covered by the domain

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $f$ is surjective if you can find $m$ and $n$ that solve the equation $m - 2n = a$ and $m - n = b$ for any two integers $a$ and $b$. Can you solve those equations for $m$ and $n$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, yes,it is possible. The entire codomain of integers is covered, thus making $f$ onto.

Answer (score 0):

You want to see whether $(x_0, y_0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ has a pre-image. If it does, then the function is surjective.

Thus, we need to solve $(m-2n,n-m)=(x_0,y_0)$ for fixed $x_0, y_0\in \mathbb{Z}$. This is solving two equations in two variables: $n=-x_0-y_0$ and $m=-2y_0-x_0$.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ just any two integers in the set of integers?

Comment: Fix an element $(x_0, y_0)\in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, so yes they can be any integers..

Answer (score 0):

Write your function as matrix multiplication:
$$f{m\choose n} ={\quad 1\quad-2\choose -1\qquad  1}{m\choose n}$$ This has $-1$ as its determinant and so the inverse exists, and has integer entries. The inverse matrix  computes the pre-image under $f$ for any given $(a,b)\in \mathbf {Z\times Z}.$